# Unique code after php link

Tags: php

I want to create a way for images to generate a short link such as domain.com/9t6So63

I want to make it 8 chars long after domain.com/ long and accept

0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

how many total generated links could i get out of this? And should i make it more?

Comment: 'Should I make it more?' That depends entirely on why you're doing this in the first place. Do you just want a random 8-character string to use as a filename?

Comment: Basically a image hosting site. With links to the image hosted on the page. domain.com/936j2t

Comment: To generate the url I'd suggest using a combination of [`hash_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php) and [`substr()`](http://uk3.php.net/substr). Remember, though, that you'll also need to store that string in a database and link it to a particular file.

Comment: http://www.technabled.com/2008/12/create-your-own-tinyurl-with-php-and.html

Comment: I am just wondering how many links total i can get out of how many chars long i specify for those letters nad numbers up there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

This is a 62 characters longs string.

If your problem is only to know the number of links you can generate, it's no more than a simple Math problem :

```
62^8 = 218,340,105,584,896
```

Answer (score 1):

> how many total generated links could i get out of this?

You would get 62^8 combinations from this.

You could use [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to generate the unique string. This string is generated based on a current time in microseconds so beware if you have multiple server instances generating the id at the same microsecond.

> With an empty prefix, the returned string will be 13 characters long. If more_entropy is TRUE, it will be 23 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Number of links are defined by the number of available characters and the length of that string, you've got twenty-six letters and ten numbers available for each position, and you're able to use each character more than once, so:

36<sup>8</sup> = 2821109907456

If you're able to use upper-case characters as well, then you've got 62 available characters for each of the eight positions, which gives a range of 62<sup>8</sup> (2821109907456) possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

This is not just a php problem, this is about [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

The number of generate "links" changes if you want to repeat or not the chars in the chosen subset.